# How to create javascript links in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="selectedpagination"  onclick="changeuploader();">
    Try flash Uploader
</a>
```

If I write in anchor tag's first parameter `javascript:void(0);`, it will open link to `controller/javascript:void(0)`

Also, how do I give it the class name and onclick event?

Comment: use  # inside href,, or try to remove that

Comment: @TechCare99 reworded things a bit, hope it still makes sense! If not, revert!

Comment: It looks like that codeigniter changes your output. The `href` looks good in my eyes. What's it changed into?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy as that:

```
anchor('#', 'Try flash Uploader', array('class'=>'selectedpagination', 'onclick'=>'changeuploader();'));
```

Check this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: what about javascript:void(0)
doesn't it need ?

Comment: use # instead...I've tested and I see that even with it...it will reload the page....I'l make some more tests and report back

Comment: `#` will make the browser move the view-port eventually.

Comment: yeah..it will...to avoid reloading the page, you can add a `return false` to your `onclick` event after your JS function. Maybe it won't work because your JS is returning something, I don't know. About move the view-port, I don't think it will be possible to solve with `anchor()`, if possible, you can create the link manually and it will work the way you need

Comment: @Gerep ... Nope. Still using core PHP Code Only.

Comment: does this link really need to be generated with PHP?

Comment: does the `changeuploader` function returns something?

Answer (score 1):

Please stop doing `<a href="javascript:void(0);" ... >`. It is an extremely bad practice. And so is attaching events in HTML.

Instead you should attach events in an external JS file. PHP framework has nothing to do with this.

Comment: you are right but the thing is that he need to use the framework to create the link and the function for that need a href and TechCare needs it to ignore the click

Comment: @tereško may be u r right , but surfing through stackoverflow, I came through this : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0  
person is having 233 Ups for his answer. 
::: More Confused :::

Comment: @TechCare99 , did you check to see which answer had bounty awarded ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0/134957#134957

Comment: @tereško ... Yes saw that too, thats why I am more confused :| 

_italic_( I am just a new to JS + jQuery !!! )

Answer (score 0):

1. onclick="**return false();**"

   $('.selectedpagination').click(function(){
       //To click here
   });
2. You can use  **button**.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find another solution instead of: $("a").removeAttr("href");

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="selectedpagination"  onclick="javascript:changeuploader();">
    Try flash Uploader
</a>
```